# MPAndroidChart inside HorizontalScrollView

Tags: java, android, charts, scrollview, mpandroidchart

(this question is also valid for ScrollView)

I need to place a `LineChart` inside `HorizontalScrollView`. I do not wish to scroll inside the chart (meaning the chart renders the scroll itself and after multiple tesst, it's quite laggy) unless it is the last solution.

The library is [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

Based on [this post on Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/forums/adding-chart-in-scroll-view) it should not be complicated.

Unfortunately I cannot seem to achieve the aimed result.

This is my XML code :

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:layout_width="2000dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:id="@+id/chart"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Nothing really fancy.

Android Studio internal designer shows a really shrinked chart and my phone does too.

What is wrong ?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: whether you got solution?

Comment: @Shadow I still don't have a solution. The chart is shrinked.

Comment: Did you find the solution of this?

Answer (score 3):

Use a LinearLayout as a container for your Line chart:

```
                    <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/hsvChart"
                    android:layout_width="800dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">
                        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                            android:id="@+id/chart"
                            android:layout_width="600dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
```

This will prevent your chart from shrinking

Comment: what if i dont want to use fixed width ? because in my application sometimes labels on x axis are small and the might change to may be 40 to 50 characters or more..

Comment: @AdeelTurk you can calculate the screen width programmatically and keep it as max width in java file

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me by setting the width match parent for horizontal view and custom width for the chart (see below code):

```
<HorizontalScrollView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="400dp"
     android:fillViewport="true">

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
         android:id="@+id/bar_chart"
         android:layout_width="800dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@color/colorWhite"
         android:padding="10dp" />
 </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```